# SQL query to pull certain rows based on values in other rows in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a set of data that contains 2 sets of identifiers: a unique number for that record, `Widget_Number`, and the original unique number for the record, `Original_Widget_Number`. Typically these two values are identical but when a record has been revised, the a new record is created with a new `Widget_Number`, preserving the old `Widget_Number` value in `Original_Widget_Number`. IE `SELECT * FROM widgets WHERE Widget_Number != Original_Widget_Number` returns all records that have been changed. (`Widget_Number` increments by 10 for new widgets and by 1 for revised widgets.)

I would like to return all records that were changed as well as the original records related to those records. For example if I had a table containing:

```
   Widget_Number    Original_Widget Number   More_Data
1:  10               10                       Stephen
2:  11               10                       Steven
3:  20               20                       Joe
```

I would like a query to return rows 1 & 2. I know I could loop trough this in a higher-level language but is there a straightforward way to do this in MS SQL?

Answer (score 1):

using `exists()`:

```
select *
from widgets as t
where exists (
  select 1
  from widgets as i
  where i.original_widget_number = t.original_widget_number
    and i.widget_number != i.original_widget_number
  )
```

or `in()`

```
select *
from widgets as t
where t.original_widget_number in (
  select i.original_widget_number
  from widgets as i
  where i.widget_number != i.original_widget_number
  )
```

Comment: Thanks! Both methods work but both are providing some duplication of the unaltered records, eg: https://pastebin.com/CmpsM4Hm. It's workable for allowing me to compare records against the originals. Any ideas how to prevent the duplication though?

Comment: @Michael It depends on which rows you want to return. You could aggregate with `group by` like `select rowid=min(rowid), widget_number, original_widget_number from .... group by widget_number, original_widget_number`

Answer (score 1):

The following should get both the records that have changed and the original records:

```
select w.*
from widgets w
where w.widget_number <> w.original_widget_number or
      exists (select 1
              from widgets w2
              where w.widget_number = w2.original_widget_number and
                    w2.widget_number <> w2.original_widget_number
             );
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but is providing some duplication of the unaltered records, eg: https://pastebin.com/CmpsM4Hm. It's workable for allowing me to compare records against the originals. Any ideas how to prevent the duplication though?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from widget
where original_widget_number in 
(select original_widget_number from widget 
 where widget_number <> original_widget_number)
```